# How to if I select the option the code also with print out the name of code

Tags: javascript, php

```
<tr>
        <td>Credit Account No: </td>
        <td><select name="debitacc">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM account";
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);

            if($count>0)
            {
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
                {
                    $code = $row['code'];
                    $id = $row['id'];

                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $code; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<option value='0'>No Account.</option>";
            }
        ?>

        </select>
        </td>

        <td>Account Name: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="creditaccname" placeholder="Enter Your Account Name"></td>
        </tr>
```

I have saved my an account in phpMyAdmin

```
id  code name
1   1234 bank charge
2   9988 CIMB
```

How do I if select the code `1234` will automatic echo in `<td> Acc` name of the code

Comment: Looks more like an HTML & JavaScript issue to me, not PHP.

Comment: Create a JavaScript object that maps the ID to the name. Add an event listener to the `<select>` so when you change it, it looks up the name in the object and displays it in the corresponding `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Code concept sample: Generate HTML/JabaScript like the following

```
<select name="DebitAccount" onchange="document.getElementById('AccountName').innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('AccountName');">
    <option value="AccountID" AccountName="AccountName">AccountCode</option>
    ...
</select>

Account name: <span id="AccountName"></span>
```

**DISCLAIMER**: There are JavaScript conformation concerns regarding inline JavaScript usage and proper HTML definition. You should follow them accordingly, I just wanted to help here with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to store the code name value as a data-attribute in the option, and then reference it at the time of selection using a `change` event.

```js
function showAccName(v) {
  let name = document.querySelector('select[name=debitacc] option:checked').dataset.name;
  document.querySelector('#accName').innerHTML = name ? `Code Type: <strong>${name}</strong>` : '';
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
  <td>Credit Account No: </td>
  <td>
    <select name="debitacc" onchange='showAccName(this.value)'>
      <option value='0'>No Account.</option>
      <option value='1' data-name="bank charge">1234</option>
      <option value='2' data-name="CIMB">9988</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>Account Name: </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="creditaccname" placeholder="Enter Your Account Name"></td>
</tr></table>

    <div id='accName'></div>
```